# MYSQL Wildcard issue for my query

Tags: mysql, sql, wildcard

ive got an issue with the mysql wildcard.
Given is the following table:

```
id | name
--------------
1  | Marcel
2  | Marcel2
3  | Marcel3
```

Now i need to know how many entrys with the name Marcel are in the table.

```
SELECT id FROM 'users' WHERE name LIKE 'Marcel#' 
--gives me **0** results

SELECT id FROM 'users' WHERE name LIKE 'Marcel_' 
-- gives me just **1** result (**3** would be the solution)
```

What query could i use to identify how often the name + nr is in the table?

Comment: Where did you get the `#` and `_` wildcard characters?  They are not part of any SQL I know of.

Comment: @wallyk From [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) `_ matches exactly one character. `. With `#` I see it first time too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%` wildcard:

```
SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE name LIKE 'Marcel%'
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02348/1/0)**</kbd>

```
%   A substitute for zero or more characters 
_   A substitute for a single character
```

So your:

> SELECT id FROM 'users' WHERE name LIKE 'Marcel_' **gives me just 1
>   result** (3 would be the solution)

may be false see: <kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02348/2/0)**</kbd> because it gives you `Marcel2` and `Marcel3` (unless you have trailing whitespaces which I cannot see in example you've provided)

Answer (score 0):

Name like '%Marcel%' Should work for you.